# Select field made in elementor is not working

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I've created a form in which there are 2 selection fields( 2 last fields in the  first image ).
When I click on the fields and areas around them , nothing is shown and I can't select anything.
what should I do now?

I thought that this problem might be from " select2-hidden-accessible"( highlighted in the second image ) but I haven't tried anything.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtK57.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkKCQ.png)